# SAS Export XML with tagset.excelxp and ods layout gridded

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, ods

I try to export **XML file** with **3 rows** and **2 columns** on same sheet like this :

[image]

with this code :

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file="mypath\Stest.xml" style=printer 
  options(
          frozen_rowheaders='no' sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='sheet1'
          embedded_titles='yes' embedded_footnotes='yes');

ods layout gridded columns=2 rows=3 /*advance=table*/;
ods region;
proc print data=table1;
title  "table1";
run;
proc print data=table2;
title  "table2";
run;
proc print data=table3;
title  "table3";
run;

ods region;

proc print data=table4;
title  "table4";
run;
proc print data=table5;
title  "table5";
run;
proc print data=table6;
title  "table6";
run;
ods layout end;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

but the results is :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you include the code for the 6 tables I would expect folks might be more willing to experiment with your program.

Comment: Will the number of rows and column names in each of the six tables always be the same?